# Proof of Borel- Cantelli Lemma , the second one, not clear, a certain detail.

Tags: probability, limits

The Lemma: If the occurrences $A_n, n=1,2,3...$ are independent and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n=\infty $ then $P(A^*)=1.$

$$P(A^*)=1-P(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k^c)=1-\lim_{n \to \infty}P( \bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k^c)$$- because $\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k^c$ is a rising set..

$$=1- \lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{m \to \infty}P(\bigcap_{k=n}^{m}A_k^c)$$-because $\bigcap_{k=n}^{m}A_k^c$ is a falling set $m > n $ it says this makes no sense how its possible..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your questions:  show
$$
\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty A_k^c 
\subseteq \bigcap_{k=2}^\infty A_k^c 
\subseteq \bigcap_{k=3}^\infty A_k^c 
\subseteq \cdots
$$
Can you do this?

The second one
$$
\bigcap_{k=7}^8 A_k^c 
\supseteq
\bigcap_{k=7}^9 A_k^c 
\supseteq
\bigcap_{k=7}^{10} A_k^c 
\supseteq \cdots
$$
Can you do this?

Comment: This I understand, that would make the sets rising

Comment: How is the other one falling I do not understand

Comment: Very well, thank you sir..